# How to place one image over another in CSS 3?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the box- shadow effect as given below .The shadow is developed using pure CSS3 code:

[image]

But due to background image ,shadow is not appearing as shown below.

[image]

How can i place the shadow on the top?

Comment: Are you using css `shadow`?

Comment: You're probably not being specific enough - Would you mind sharing a jsfiddle with the markup and css?

Comment: Share your code please, so that we can help :)

Comment: we cannot help if we dont see your source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an image for the shadow you will need to relatively position it and use z-indexing. As the above post suggests can you be a bit more specific though?

Comment: :I am not using image for the shadow.I only want the shadow to appear above the background-image.Shadow is developed using css 3

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this would do the work for you

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="image1.jpg" style="position:absolute; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: 1;"/>
  <img src="image2.jpg" style="position:absolute; top: 80px; left: 25px; z-index: 3;"/>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.